# PhantomJs prints SVG source code instead of rendering it

Tags: svg, phantomjs, rasterizing

I have set up a new Windows machine where I would like to rasterize a bunch of SVG documents to PNG images. I have simplified Ariya Hidayat's [rasterize](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) script to this :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    svgPath, output;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL output');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    svgPath = fs.workingDirectory + '/' + system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 120 };

    if (!fs.isFile(svgPath)) {
        console.log(svgPath+' does not exist');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }

    page.onLoadFinished = function() {
        page.render(output);
        console.log('thumbnail created');
        phantom.exit(0);
    };

    page.open(svgPath);
}
```

And here is how I call the script : `bin\phantomjs js/headless/rasterize.js "simple.svg" "simple.svg.png" 2>&1`

`simple.svg` contains this data :

```
<svg width="110" height="60" id="simple" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="50" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
</svg>
```

Once the script has been executed (without error), `simple.svg.png` is rendered like this :
[image: simple.svg.png]

This is really strange, and I'm pretty sure the thumbnail was correctly generated on the previous machine. Why does it just render the SVG's source code ?

Comment: Test your phatomjs with their stock SVG `phantomjs rasterize.js http://ariya.github.io/svg/tiger.svg tiger.png`, if that works then try it without `2>&1` which redirects the stderr to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works indeed when using an HTTP-based (and not file-based) SVG. I solved the problem by creating a local server so that the SVG content type could be handled when renderning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that I load the SVG from the file system, and PhantomJS has no way of knowing that I want to show the SVG as an image and not as a text. 
The solution was to instantiate a [local server](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) where I can load the SVG from the file system and configure the content type to make it be actually rendered like you would expect an SVG to be :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = require('webserver').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    svgPath, output;

var serverUrl = '127.0.0.1:8888';

server.listen(serverUrl, function (request, response) {
    var cleanedUrl = request.url
        .replace(/\//g, fs.separator)
        .replace(/\?.*$/g, '');
    var pagePath = fs.workingDirectory + cleanedUrl;
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml");
    try {
        response.write(fs.read(pagePath));
    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Error while reading ' + cleanedUrl + '(requested URL : '+request.url+')');
        response.close();
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    response.close();
});

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL output');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    svgPath = fs.workingDirectory + '/' + system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 120 };

    if (!fs.isFile(svgPath)) {
        console.log(svgPath+' does not exist');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }

    page.onLoadFinished = function() {
        page.render(output);
        console.log('thumbnail created');
        server.close();
        phantom.exit(0);
    };

    page.open('http://'+serverUrl+'/'+system.args[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result when executing the conversion via Java's ProcesBuilder while it worked fine when launching it via cmdline. I've tried to prefix the source file with file:// protocol, e.g. `file:///D:/phantomjs/test.svg` and it works as expected in my case.